# Find/Replace in File Field

Tags: database, files

I'm working with a site that has many files that have been uploaded to it. Data has been pulled from these files to populate fields such as title, description, etc. Some of these fields contained ampersands which now appear as &.

Is there a way I can batch correct these—such as a find/replace? I tried the Find/Replace Scanner module but it doesn't seem to be able to work with file nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find the file field in question in your database.

1. Export it as csv.
2. Use find and replace with excel, save.
3. Import it back in.
4. Clear the cache.